# Storage array cant be pinged from the server

Tags: process

Built a storage array with windows 10, its on the same network as my server and wipestations. i can ping the server from the storage array but i cant ping the storage array from the server without turning the firewall off. The array itself is hardwired into the server. What can i do to get the server to ping the array without turning the firewall off.

P.S. im new to networking and would appreciate a hand.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "_storage array_"? I'm presuming you're using a NAS?

Comment: Even if you're unable to `ping`, can you reach other services (like samba / file sharing)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permit incoming ping requests, activate (or create) the firewall rule which permits incoming ping requests. The Windows Firewall really isn't all-or-nothing; you can configure it via `wf.msc`. The rules are under "Inbound Rules", all labelled "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request)".